# sync and async in anychart doesn't show in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, asynchronous, anychart

I am working on sync and async rendering in [anychart](https://www.anychart.com/), I have created four buttons to show Sync chart,async chart,display time and numberofclicks. when I make 
`async= true` and click on time and `numberofclick` it works, and when I make `sync=false` then stop working which the chart renders, everything looks good till now with all the other browsers Chrome, Firefox but problem starts with IE. I can't see async rendering nor I am able to click time or `numberofclicks`. It behaves like `sync` not `async`.

I made an ajax call and mentioned `(sync:true)` but see same sync rendering chart.

Can anyone suggest how to see the async rendering in (IE10 or IE11).

Comment: To investigate this situation we'd like to take a look at the code. Could you provide us this code or fiddle to simulate the same behavior and find a solution?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the entire solution as it has model and business logic but i have provided the client side code.Below is the link for fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Akhileshkumar/hg5swk0r/ ). In my application when I make chart async=true I see rendering and was able to perform another events like click time and  counter in  Chrome and FireFox but IE doesn't show the result until the chart loads completely if i make async=true and click the button time and counter.

Comment: We reproduced the same situation using your fiddle and this is definitely a bug. It was reported to our dev team. We will fix it in future releases.